# X velocity slowing down when applying Y Linear Impulse with Box2D

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm using libgdx and box2d as my physics engine. Right now I just have a very simple box being controlled on a single flat surface:

[image]

Everything seems to be working well. I control the box with the arrow keys. If I press the right arrow the box will accelerate to the right. When I press the up arrow, the box will jump. **Something that was unexpected though was that when the box jumps, it's x velocity slows down. Can anyone tell me why that is and how to fix it?**

**Player Object with just some Box2d setup:**

```
public class Player extends Entity {
  private static BodyDef createBodyDef() {
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
    bodyDef.position.set(100, 200);
    return bodyDef;
  }

  public Player(World world) {
    super(world, createBodyDef(), Textures.rectangle(Units.m2P(0.7f), Units.m2P(2f), Color.RED));
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(50, 50, new Vector2(50, 50), 0f);
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.1f;
    getBody().createFixture(fixtureDef);
    MassData massData = new MassData();
    massData.mass = 90f;
    getBody().setMassData(massData);
  }
}
```

**The Game Screen:**

```
public class GameScreen extends BaseScreen implements InputProcessor {
  private final World world = new World(new Vector2(0, -200), false);
  private final GameView view = new GameView();
  private final List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
  private final Player player = new Player(world);
  private final List<Integer> pressedKeys = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public GameScreen() {
    entities.add(player);
    view.setFollowEntity(player);
    MapBodyBuilder.buildShapes(view.getTiledMap(), 1, world);
  }

  @Override public void show() {
    super.show();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
  }

  @Override public void render(float delta) {
    super.render(delta);

    float forceX = 0f;
    float forceY = 0f;
    float force = 15000;
    if (pressedKeys.contains(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
      forceX -= force;
    }
    if (pressedKeys.contains(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
      forceX += force;
    }
    if (pressedKeys.contains(Input.Keys.DOWN)) {
      forceY -= force;
    }

    player.getBody().applyForceToCenter(forceX, forceY, false);

    world.step(delta, 5, 5);
    view.render(entities);
  }

  @Override public void resize(int width, int height) {
    super.resize(width, height);
  }

  @Override public void hide() {
    super.hide();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
  }

  @Override public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    world.dispose();
    for (Entity entity : entities) {
      entity.dispose();
    }
  }

  @Override public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.UP) {
      Body body = player.getBody();
      body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 30000), body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }

    pressedKeys.add(keycode);
    return false;
  }

  @Override public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    pressedKeys.remove((Integer) keycode);
    return false;
  }

  @Override public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
  }

  public Player getPlayer() {
    return player;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see how your moving mechanism works:

1. Calculate forceX and forceY (due to what keys are pressed)
2. Apply forceX and forceY

of course you cannot use it to jump to avoid "flying" so you are using **applyLinearImpulse()** to add force once (just push it to the top) but the tricky part is that you are cancelling forceX you added in **2.** - remember that in Box2D all forces executes on the world.step(...) execution **after all calculations**

Instead of

```
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.UP) 
    {
        Body body = player.getBody();
        body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 30000), body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }
```

do something like

```
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.UP) 
    {
        jumpForce = 30000; //jumpForce is variable of GameScreen class
    }
```

and then in the **render** method

```
    ...

    if (pressedKeys.contains(Input.Keys.DOWN)) 
    {
        forceY -= force;
    }

    forceY += jumpForce; //here you add the jump force

    player.getBody().applyForceToCenter(forceX, forceY, false);

    jumpForce = 0; //but only once - in next iteration od render it will be avoided till UP key will be pressed again
```

Of course you can think about your own mechanism but this is the right direction